# Failing to sign a transaction using eth_sign

Tags: web3js, metamask

```
async function sendEth() {
    const txData = {
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(25000),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(25e9), // 25 Gwei
        from: web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress,
        to: destinationAddres,
        value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10000000000000000', 'wei'))
    }

    const params = ["ADDRESS", txData]

    console.log(web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress);
    const signature = await ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_sign',
        params: params
    });
    console.log(signature);
```

Hi, I am trying to make a wallet connected to my frontend to sign a transaction using the eth_sign method. I know this is decrapated but I'd like to use it anyway because Metamask does not allow signtransaction.

Unfortunately upon letting an user sign this message i get the following error:

`inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: e.slice is not a function`

Comment: `eth_sign` is expecting a string as second parameter and you are sending a javascript object. Also you cannot use `eth_sign` to sign a transaction, for signing a transaction you have to use `eth_signTransaction`. Check the walletconnect documentation https://docs.walletconnect.com/json-rpc-api-methods/ethereum#eth_signtransaction.

Comment: Hi, by now ive managed to serialize the tx to a hex and send that along.
I read that eth_sign allows you to send an arbitrary hash though.

https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#signing-data-with-metamask

Comment: AFAIK `eth_sign` cannot be used to sign a transaction. In my tests most wallets use the prefix "\x19Ethereum Signed Message\n" for `eth_sign`, and transaction do not have such prefix.